# Correct syntax for Objective-C init method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Why doesn't this common property initialization scheme risk failure when the synthesized setter tries to release the undefined myArray object? Or are property objects automatically initialized to nil and I don't need to be doing this at all?

```
@interface myClass : NSObject {
    NSArray* myArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* myArray;
@end

@implementation myClass
@synthesize myArray;
-(id)init {
    if ( self = [super init] ) {
        self.myArray = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As others have stated, the instance variable is already initialised to `nil`.

Additionally, [as per Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW11), instance variables should be set directly in an `init` method, as the getter/setter methods of a class (or subclass thereof) may rely on a fully initialised instance.

Comment: "as the getter/setter methods of a class (or subclass thereof) may rely on a fully initialised instance" do you have the source of this? Thanks!

Comment: I certainly do, it's in the Apple docs. I'll edit my answer to include a reference.

Comment: "Swift answer"? Isn't this Objective-C?

Answer (score 28):

Object instance variables in Objective-C are initialized to `nil` by default. Furthermore, messaging `nil` is allowed (unlike calling a method on `null` in function-calling languages like Java, C# or C++). The result of a message to `nil` is `nil`, this calling `[nil release];` is just `nil`, not an exception.

On a side note, it's best practice to assign/call instance variables directly in `-init` and `-dealloc` methods:

```
-(id)init {
    if ( self = [super init] ) {
        myArray = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [myArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's already initialized to `nil`.